# Yii2 save model to database

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I'm trying to do simple CRUD application with Yii2, but when I'm trying to save data, no validation errors appears and `$model->validate()` returns false. Here's my code:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Game();
    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save())
    {
        $this->redirect(['game-list']);
    }
    return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

So, `$model->load()` returns true and here is my `rules()` in my model:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['title', 'subtitle', 'description'], 'required'],
        [['id_type', 'is_active', 'picture'], 'default'],
    ];
}
```

I have seven columns in DB (this 6 + id as a primary key). I will be glad if anyone help me.

**UPD:**
View:

```
<? $form = ActiveForm::begin(array('options' => array('class' => 'form-horizontal'))); ?>
<?= $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'subtitle')->textInput(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textInput(); ?>
<div class="form-actions">
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', $model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update')); ?>
</div>
<? ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: Post your view file. Also, Default validator expects value attribute to be set.

Comment: yes, I've tried to set value before, but it doesn't worked anyway

Comment: `$model->save()` calls `validate`. Check [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#manipulating-data-in-database) and I've already tried to call `validate()` just in case, no errors in `$model->getErrors()`

Comment: Have you tried to call $model->getErrors()?

Comment: Are the fields `id_type`, `is_active` and `picture` allowed to have a null value? If not, the model cannot be saved but no validation errors will be generated because no validation rules are defined.

Comment: I've tried to set different default values, so `picture` have an empty string and `id_type`, `is_active` are set with `1`. Anyway, I'll try to dig at this point, when I able to.

Comment: I've changed database as @Barry recommended, still getting same results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My mistake was obviously stupid, but here it is. I've created method `beforeSave` in my model and haven't filled it and totally forgot about it's existence. So, 'cause it's not returned true - `validate()` cannot pass properly. Sorry for wasted time.